# How do I place my ship in the equator of a planet?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I sent a ship to Duna.

How do I check or know if my ship is orbiting the equator of that body?

I do know how to orbit a body. I want to know specifically about orbiting the equator.

Note: I don't want to install Kerbal Engineer Redux since a good amount of the useful features were already integrated to the game.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to orbit exactly the equator? Do you accept an error margin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution without using any mod:
1- Click on the button pointed by the blue arrow. It's the **Maneuver Mode**
2- Click on the button pointed by the green arrow. It's the **Advanced orbital info**

When the inclination is 0 (zero), you are orbiting the equator.

[image: solution]